# When I publish a ASP.NET MVC 3 project my Razor views aren't copied

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Looks like Publish doesn't copy Razor views at ASP.NET MVC 3 Beta. Is it a known limitation of Beta? Will it be fixed at release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try selecting a razor file and in the properties make sure that `Build Action` is set to `Content`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure.  Best way is to submit it as a bug in the connect.microsoft.com web site.